# Google Maps Web Service Api

Tags: google-maps

I created for a taxi site an automatic suggestion result in the booking form using google maps web service api, but some location are not returned correctly or not consistent. For example if I search for "Milan Central Station" i receive the correct location, with train icon etc.. if I search for "Roma Termini Station" (the first big train station in italy) i receive the generic address of the station and business generic icon.. Someone know how can I manipulate response to show separated predictions? In google maps for roma termini station input are predict different suggestions

The code with a google response

```
<script>   

    string='roma termini station';

    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById('GoogleMapService'));

    var request = {
        query: string,
    };

    service.textSearch(request, function(result){ 

         console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see Places autocomplete for 'Milan Central Station' returns place ID ChIJQ1j3T8XGhkcRKs-XGhSxJiI. When you request places details you can see that types are: "train_station","transit_station","point_of_interest","establishment"

In case of 'Roma Termini Station' the Place ID is ChIJ7__AOaRhLxMRlKlh8r59MKQ and details returns the following types:

"transit_station","train_station","bus_station","point_of_interest","establishment"

So, the place for Roma Termini Station is marked both as a train station and as a bus station. I think Google return a generic icon due to this ambiguity.

Not sure if this is intended behavior or data issue. If you believe this is a data issue please use Send feedback link of Google maps:

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/162873

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks xomena, maybe in the next future google will improve search for missing items